# z-index not working on div tag

Tags: css, html, z-index

I am using div tag with position absolute. But its not working properly. I wish to put login box on top of everything else. When i tried to change position:absolute of login div, it messes everything.

```
<body>

<div id="login">
    <a href="#">Login</a>
    <div>
        Login Form
        Lorem Ipsum blablbalbabababa lbablaabalbalba
    </div>
</div>
    <p style="position:absolute;z-index:-99;top:30px;"> hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhkj</p>
</body>
```

See here http://jsfiddle.net/jPPew/44/

Comment: What do you mean by "messes everything"?

Comment: it expanded the width of link login and paragraph breaks the login div and another div. See fiddle pls.

Comment: In your fiddle, it is working but since you have applied transparent using rgba(,,,.2). It looks like not working.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Sorry for this stupid post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it IS on top. I guess you think this isn't because it has alpha 0.2 (background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);) and thats why you can see through it ;)